# Azure DevOps - How do I set security properly on Repo

Tags: git, security, azure-devops

I have a repo in Azure DevOps that I would like to prevent members of the Contributors group from beng able to contribute to. I know about branch policies, but I don't want to use those on this particular repo, I just want to prevent these users from being able to do anything to this repo except for reading it.  So what I tried was to Deny the Contributors group those rights on this repo, as shown below:

[image: Denying the Contributors group]

However, when I do this change, then members of the other groups are unable to contribute to the Repo as well, which is not what I want. For example, I'm a member of the Project Administrators group, but I can no longer modify files in this repo after this change has been made.

Is there a way to prevent members of the Contributors group from being able to contribute to this Repo, but still allow members of other groups, like Project Administrators, or specific users like Project Collection Build Service, be able to still contribute to the Repo?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because at least one of these is true:

1. The Contributors group also contains some of the other groups.
2. Some of the users in other groups are also in the Contributors group.

That, combined with the fact that if any user has **Allow** and **Deny** for the same permission, **Deny** will take precedent.

The first thing to try is to change all the **Deny** to **Not set** for Contributors. (All of those settings in your screenshot.) The "Not set" permission means that you are denied the permission unless you are given it another way. This should fix it unless the only reason people in the other groups had the contribute permission set was due to the Contributors previously having **Allow** there, or if you see "Allow (inherited)". In the latter case, the next thing to try is to turn off inheritance for this repo only, and then the **Not set** permission should no longer provide access to anything. If you do this though you'll probably want to step through all permission in the repo to confirm they remain what you desire.

If neither of those will work for you, then you could create a new group with the permissions you created above, and then put all the people in that group that should have read-only. Then the **Deny** will only apply to them specifically. This doesn't scale well though as new users are added to your system, so I'd prefer to figure it out using inheritance and **Not set** rules.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I had tried the Not set previously but that would still not allow access for the Contributors group, so it's like you said, something else must be denying it.